# Add hardware reset button for Create2

Tags: irobot-create

Is there any way to add a reset button to the Create2 that would be the equivalent  of temporarily disconnecting the battery?

Comment: See also: [Create2 kill switch](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/11611/create-2-kill-switch)

Answer (score 3):

There is no good way to do this by hacking in a switch because the battery goes right into the main PCB, but you do have two other good options.

1. [Send opcode 7](http://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf): "This command resets the robot, as if you had removed and reinserted the battery"
2. [Press and hold the SPOT and DOCK buttons for 10 seconds](http://homesupport.irobot.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8244/~/roomba-docks-too-soon-with-a-fully-charged-battery).

Answer (score 2):

You could put a [momentary switch](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/category/716200/switches-pushbutton/momentary/1.html) on the battery line. That would *actually* temporarily disconnect the battery.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I had thought of the momentary switch, but as Ben says the battery configuration makes it hard to get to. The whole purpose of the reset is to avoid the awkward 10 second 2 button sequence. I think I've done that literally 100's of times. Sending the opcode isn't a good solution because we are running these wirelessly and often the reset is because we've lost communications. I have an idea on how to get a switch inline with the battery - I will follow up if it works.