# Create 2 kill switch?

Tags: irobot-create

Any ideas on ways to install a kill switch on the Create 2?  I saw how the battery attaches to the main board with springs, so that blocks me from using a plain old battery switch.  Are there any test points that can be grounded to shut down when in full mode?

Comment: See also: [Add hardware reset button for Create2](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/8001/add-hardware-reset-button-for-create2)

Answer (score 2):

Something I've always wanted to try (but never have) is to use two pieces of copper tape, back-to-back (with something thin and insulating like packing tape between them) to interrupt the connection between the one of the spring terminals and one of the battery contacts. Then, this thin conductor sandwich could be brought out to somewhere more convenient to install a kill switch. (You could solder wires to the copper tape once you're somewhere less constrained.) Let us know how it goes!

Please note that I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.

Comment: I guess it would be an insulator sandwich; the copper tape conductors would be the bread. But I digress.